# Container not able to access folder mounted from NFS storage class in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

Have a cluster configured using Rancher, Defined a pv with NFS storage class.

In a pod mounted a directory from nfs /nfs-share/myapp/data to /apps/data/

The application uses the configuration to create a temp file on specified path.

When I uses `/apps/data/myfolder` the application reports access deined to access this folder.

```
$ ls -lrt /apps 
drwxrwxrwx.  8 nobody nobody   238 Sep  4  2023 data
```

```
$ ls -lrt /apps/data/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1000 nobody 4.0K Oct  2 03:13 myfolder
```

The pod includes below

```
  securityContext:
    capabilities:
      drop:
        - ALL
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsNonRoot: true
```

Exec'ed into container and below is the id info, and I am able to navigate to the folder without any issue

```
$ id 
uid=1000 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

```
$ getent group
root:x:0:
...
nobody:x:65534:
appuser:x:1001:
```

When I use the configuration to different folder in the container `/apps/option/` applicaiton is able to accessing that folder path.

The details of the /apps/ and permissions of option folder looks like below

```
$ ls -lrth /apps
drwxr-xr-x. 10   1000 appuser 4096 Oct  6 23:08 option
```

```
$ ls -lrht /apps/option
total 2M
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 appuser 1.1K Oct  2 19:04 startupscript.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 appuser  10K Oct  2 19:16 version.txt
```

I am not sure why user 1000 not able to access `/apps/data/myfolder` but `/apps/option`. Any troubleshooting tips.

**Reason for NOT AN ISSUE**

Issue occurred since there were no space in the disk and trying to create some file through application. freed up some space and that fixed the accessed denied issue.

Comment: At a high level

- App is NOT able to access below folder, I can access when exec to the running container

`
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1000 nobody 4.0K Oct  2 03:13 myfolder
`

- App is able to access below folder

`
drwxr-xr-x. 10   1000 appuser 4096 Oct  6 23:08 option
`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
chown -R 1000 /apps/data/myfolder
```

?

as this is assigned to `nobody` now:

```
$ ls -lrt /apps 
drwxrwxrwx.  8 nobody nobody   238 Sep  4  2023 data
```

> or the YOLO version (which is not recommended as it allows basically everything to everyone)
>
> ```
> chmod -R 777 /apps/data/myfolder
> ```

Comment: My bad, it was a space issue which caused this access denied for my specific use case. That configuration mentioned in the question worked, after freeing up the space.